# Visual Studio Installer Project: RemovePreviousVersions does not seem to work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm trying to build a Visual Studio Installer Project that is possible to upgrade. I've followed all of the recommendations in MS's documentation I can find:

- I start versioning the installer at 1.0.0 and increment it by major version (2.0.0, 3.0.0, etc).
- I change the Product Code each time I change the installer version.
- I leave the Upgrade Code the same for each installer version.

When I go in and check Add/Remove Programs, I can see the new version of my installer package successfully "installed". I can see that any previous installed versions are no longer there. Great.

**BUT**

The files the installer writes to Program Files never change. The application binaries remain the same from installation to installation. I cannot figure out why this is. I've deleted the built installer MSIs, I've cleaned my solution 100 times, I've done every thing  I can to ensure that previous versions of my application binaries are not being included in the new MSI, but I cannot seem to get this to work. The oldest version of my application always exists in Program Files after newer installations.

Any ideas?

Comment: A changed Product Code allows both the original version and the update to co-exist.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: That's not the impression I got from MS's documentation.

Comment: That's why I'm so interested in RemovePreviousVersions - so original version and the update do not co-exist.